# Need help formatting date into my activerecord migration column

Tags: ruby, activerecord, command-line-interface

I am working on a CLI app based on ActiveRecord migration, and I am trying to set one of the table columns to have a t.date property so that the users can check open availability during certain dates. The trouble I am having is how to format my date when I create a new instance of my class. [Created instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsZKI.png)

As of now, I just have 2020 integer in there so I can test out my other methods but I will need to get this situated before I move on to the more advanced methods. I have tried to use mm/dd/yyyy format in "" and without, as well as mm-dd-yyyy and some other fomrats. Not sure it should be a string, or just integer values.

I hope I am asking my question correctly.

[image: Table Creation class]

Comment: Can you please show us your class where you define the date field, it's impossible to give you the correct formatting with out knowing how you declared it.

Comment: My fault I thought I uploaded bot pictures. I edited my original post to include the migration class

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812)". Images of code and errors do not work well except as ancillary information, having it in code we can reuse and modify is the primary tool for helping you and those who search for the same solution in the future.

Comment: @theTinMan, thanks. Sorry about that, I will be more aware in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that you would be able to create the date in a variety of different ways before passing it to your function.

Please see the below image for some examples of ways you could create a date object.

[Ruby date and datetime class - Tadayoshi Funaba 1998-2011](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In my instance would I create a date class, have it belong to my festival class and use that as a foreign key in my table?

Comment: The date class already exists as long as you require it. So I would simply do something like `require 'date'` then create your date `mydate = Date.parse('2010-02-03')` then pass that to your Festival.create call `gmb = Festival.create(...... , date: mydate)`

Comment: thank you so much. It clicks seeing it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Aidan, please read See "[What happens if you answered a question, questioner says thanks, but didn't accept your answer as correct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109773)" and "[Do you feel dirty if you nudge new users to accept your answer when they indicate you've answered their question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994)" Also, please don't use images to document languages. Provide a link and copy and paste the minimal information into your answer that supplies the needed information. Nobody can reuse the image in their code, but they can copy it or search.

Comment: Out of touch, been on ServiceNow community forums too long, read that and you'll understand. Thanks for the reminder